# Disk map software needed

Tags: disk-space, disk-utility

I'm looking for some disk mapping software for Windows (a software that graphically displays disk space usage) that doesn't use [Cushion Treemaps](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example3.html).

Comment: Boo! Just use WinDirStat and be happy with the CTs it generates.

Answer (score 4):

[Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) is a nice little app, it displays disk space as concentric circles and let's you navigate trough the disk byt clicking on the circle areas. Plus, the sources are available !

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/). The interface may look a little dated but one useful part is that you can assign different colours to different filetypes, for example, yellow to all .mp3 files. Then all the yellow dots are .mp3 files. It's designated "squared treemaps" if that's OK...

Comment: Thanks but it uses Cushion Treemaps...

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found [JDiskReport!](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)

Why this software is great:
1 - It's very light - using Java version.
2 - Has more than one graph options (pie, ring, bars or table).
3 - Graph is interactive (you can click it areas for further navigation).
4 - Can show you list of 50 largest files, size distribution, modified distribution or type distribution.
5 - Best of all: it's free, open-source and cross-plataform.